# ROS2 launch: subscriber not receiving data

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch

I'm using ROS2 humble under Windows. I have a very simple PyQt based publisher and subscriber:

**Publisher:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor

from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

import threading

import math
import sys

class Gui:

    def __init__(self,publisher):
        self.publisher = publisher

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setText("Press to reset publisher")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.publisher.resetCounter)
        self.layout.addWidget( self.pushButton )

        self.widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
        
        self.widget.show()

        self.publisher.widget = self.widget

class DummyPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('dummy_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(ChannelFloat32, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.resetCounter()

        self.widget = None

        self.t0 = self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = ChannelFloat32()
        msg.values = [ float((self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds-self.t0)/1e9), float(self.i), float(math.sin(self.i)), float(self.i*4) ]
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"\n' % str(msg.values))
        self.i += 1

        if self.widget:
            self.widget.setWindowTitle("Dummy publisher " + str(self.i))

    def resetCounter(self):
        self.i = 0

def ros_node_thread(ros_node):
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(ros_node)
    executor.spin()

def main(args=None):
    
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    publisher = DummyPublisher()
    gui = Gui( publisher )

    ros_node_thread_instance = threading.Thread(target=ros_node_thread, args=(publisher,))
    ros_node_thread_instance.start()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    finally:
        publisher.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()
        ros_node_thread_instance.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Subscriber:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor

from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer
import PyQt5.QtCore

import threading
import sys

class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
        
        self.widget.show()

class DummyListener(Node):

    def __init__(self,gui):
        super().__init__('dummy_listener')
        self.gui = gui
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            ChannelFloat32,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

        self.gui = gui
        self.count = 0

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % str(msg.values))

        self.count += 1

        self.gui.widget.setWindowTitle("Dummy listener " + str(self.count))


def ros_node_thread(ros_node):
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(ros_node)
    executor.spin()

def main(args=None):
    
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = Gui()
    listener = DummyListener( gui )
    
    ros_node_thread_instance = threading.Thread(target=ros_node_thread, args=(listener,))
    ros_node_thread_instance.start()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    finally:
        listener.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()
        ros_node_thread_instance.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute them from different consoles, running:

```
ros2 run my_package talker
ros2 run my_package listener
```

It just works fine, I see the two widgets, one with `Dummy publisher #` title being incremented and one with `Dummy listener #` title being incremented.

However, when I use a laucnh script:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            namespace= "talker", package='my_package', executable='talker'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            namespace= "listener", package='my_package', executable='listener'),
    ])
```

The, I see the first widget with `Dummy publisher #` title being incremented and the other one's title remains unchanged as "python". By looking deeper, I see `listener_callback` never gets called.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `namespace`.

With:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            namespace= "talker", package='my_package', executable='talker'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            namespace= "listener", package='my_package', executable='listener'),
    ])
```

Nodes end up in different namespaces. So subscriber should do:

```
self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
    ChannelFloat32,
    '/talker/topic',  # Adjust the topic namespace
    self.listener_callback,
    10)
```

Or, original posted subscriber code will work with no namespace used:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='my_package', executable='talker'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='my_package', executable='listener'),
    ])
```

Note: This solution was given to me by ChatGPT...